# Conditions under which capacitor is going to be short circuited and open circuited

Tags: capacitor, capacitance

In which conditions, capacitor is going to be short circuited and capacitor is going to be open circuited.

When capacitor is completely discharged, can we say it is open circuited , since there is no conduction.

I want to know in what situations, capacitor acts as open circuit and short circuit.

Comment: (I would advise you to go to your previous questions and give feedback to those who have dedicated their time to help you out... you have not accepted their answers as a solution that you're looking for. Hit the check mark under the vote system if you found the answer as the solution you're looking for. Thanks!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During a transient response of an RC circuit, after a long period of time, the capacitor can be treated like an **open circuit**. There's another instance where if you study the small signal analysis of a BJT or MOSFET circuits, capacitors will be treated like a **short circuit** (not to be confused with the natural capacitances that occur on semiconductor devices, i.e. overlap capacitance, parasitic capacitances etc.)

Comment: Also in transient analysis, initially at t=0, an uncharged capacitor is considered short when connected to a DC voltage source.

Comment: Where the check mark is located.